# How to initialize/load aurelia-dialog plugin correctly before running test cases?

Tags: javascript, webpack, jasmine, aurelia, aurelia-dialog

I have a service (no view) that depends on `DialogService` from `aurelia-dialog`, and uses that for opening a dialog. I want to test my service. While doing that I got the following error on `dialogService.open(...)`.

> Error: DialogRenderer must implement getDialogContainer().
>
> at Renderer.getDialogContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/aurelia-dialog/dist/native-modules/renderer.js:14:15)
>
> at DialogService.open (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/aurelia-dialog/dist/native-modules/dialog-service.js:139:106) ...

I got the [idea that I need to load the plugin `aurelia-dialog`](https://github.com/aurelia/dialog/issues/155#issuecomment-376503787) before running any of test cases. To this end, I tried the following.

```
import { bootstrap } from "aurelia-bootstrapper";
import { Aurelia, Container, PLATFORM } from "aurelia-framework";

describe("test specs", () => {
    let container: Container;

    beforeAll(async () => {

        await bootstrap(async (aurelia: Aurelia) => {
            aurelia.use
                .standardConfiguration()
                .developmentLogging()
                .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName("aurelia-dialog"), (config) => {
                    config.useDefaults();
                    config.settings.lock = true;
                    config.settings.centerHorizontalOnly = false;
                    config.settings.startingZIndex = 5;
                    config.settings.keyboard = true;
                });

            Container.instance = container = new Container();
            aurelia.container = container;
            await aurelia.start();
        });
    });
});
```

But than I got the following error on `aurelia.start`.

> Error: Loader must implement loadAllModules(ids).
>
> at Loader.loadAllModules (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/aurelia-loader/dist/native-modules/aurelia-loader.js:113:11)
>
> at ViewEngine.importViewResources (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/native-modules/aurelia-templating.js:3593:24)
>
> at eval (webpack-internal:///aurelia-framework:646:23)
>
> at <Jasmine>
>
> at loadResources (webpack-internal:///aurelia-framework:637:7)
>
> at eval (webpack-internal:///aurelia-framework:731:14)
>
> at next (webpack-internal:///aurelia-framework:577:30)
>
> at runTasks (webpack-internal:///aurelia-framework:583:10)
>
> at eval (webpack-internal:///aurelia-framework:936:16)
>
> at <Jasmine>
>
> at eval (webpack-internal:///aurelia-framework:935:21)
>
> at <Jasmine>
>
> at FrameworkConfiguration.apply (webpack-internal:///aurelia-framework:919:42)
>
> at Aurelia.start (webpack-internal:///aurelia-framework:463:37) ...

Thus, my question is how to correctly load the `aurelia-dialog` plugin in this scenario?